# Single user unable to copy/paste on Samba share

Tags: samba

So a user is trying to setup a service account (created under active directory) to run a script against a samba share. All this script does is tell the service account to copy file A from location 1 (samba location), to location 2 (windows  location). However it is unable to do this.

I have added the account to the samba.conf file and we verified from Windows that we can connect to the drive with the account, however we can't copy/paste with it.

From what we can tell the account only has read permissions on the folder, however we have at the same times the user is able to run the script with his own AD account (also listed in the samba.conf file). I don't see their personal user account added to any groups on the linux box, and I don't see any special groups on the windows side, that the users personal account is added to, that the service account is not added too.

I've been researching, but I just can't figure out why this one account is having the issue.

Comment: Please include the `[global]` section and the appropriate `[share]` section from `smb.conf`. Also look in the log files under `/var/log/sama` for a recently modified file whose name corresponds to the client's IP address or machine name, and see what error messages are presented in it

Comment: What are the unix permissions on the file trying to be copied (ie.  ls -lh) and what is the samba username/group trying to read the file?